# CSS color property on Jquery Chaining method

Tags: jquery

i want to apply two color property on an element with Jquery chaining method but only one is working

```
$("#p1").css("color", "red").slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000).css("color","green");
```

Answer (score 1):

Set css property after completing the **[slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)** , for that you can use callback function

```js
$("#p1").css("color", "red").slideUp(2000).slideDown(2000,function(){
  $(this).css("color","green");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="p1">hiiiiii</div>
```